# Number of edges in a graph construction

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose we have a graph on the vertex set $[n]^m$, i.e, each vertex is of the form $(v_1, ..., v_m)$, where each $v_i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.

We draw an edge between two vertices $v = (v_1, ..., v_m)$ and $u = (u_1, ..., u_m)$ iff $u_i = v_i$ for some $i \in [m]$. My question is, how many edges are in our graph?

My attempt:

We clearly have $n^m$ vertices. Fix some $v = (v_1, ..., v_m)$. Then the number of vertices in which every entry is different from $v$ is $(n-1)^m$, so $v$ has $n^m -1- (n-1)^m $ neighbours (the $-1$ is to avoid counting $v$ itself). By the handshake lemma, the number of edges in the graph is $$\frac{1}{2}n^m(n^m -1- (n-1)^m).$$
Is this correct? Does this mean the number of edges is asymptotically proportional to $n^{2m}$? I'm not sure why this seems wrong to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is correct; there are indeed $\frac12 n^m(n^m - (n-1)^m - 1)$ edges in this graph.

The asymptotics are a bit trickier. When there are two variables involved, our asymptotic analysis has to be done with an understanding of which variable is going to infinity - or if both of them are, how quickly relative to each other they are doing so.

Taking the expression $\frac12 n^m (n^m - (n-1)^m - 1)$ and dismissing $(n-1)^m$ (and $1$) as a lower-order term relative to $n^m$ is fair if $n$ is constant as $m \to \infty$. More generally, it is valid if $\frac{(n-1)^m}{n^m} \to 0$ as $n$ and $m$ go to $\infty$ at their own paces, which happens when $\frac nm \to 0$ as $n$ and $m$ go to $\infty$.

If $m \sim cn$ for a constant $c$, then $(n-1)^m \sim e^{-c} n^m$, and so the number of edges is asymptotically more like $\frac12 e^{-c} n^{2m}$, or $\frac12 e^{-m/n} n^{2m}$. (It's still fair to say that the number of edges is asymptotically proportional to $n^{2m}$ here, but only if we ignore the constant factor.)

On the other hand, suppose $m$ is constant as $n \to \infty$. Then by expanding $(n-1)^m$ as $$n^m - m n^{m-1} + \binom m2 n^{m-2} - \binom m3 n^{m-3} + \dots \pm 1$$ with the binomial theorem, we see that the $n^m$'s cancel, and the leading leftover term is $m n^{m-1}$. Here, the number of edges is asymptotically $\frac12 m n^{2m-1}$ as $n \to \infty$. This last analysis remains valid if $\frac mn \to 0$ as $m$ and $n$ go to $\infty$, since this ensures that the later terms of the binomial sum have lower order compared to $m n^{m-1}$.

---

We can also reason through this intuitively, though our intuition can't get us the precise results. What would it mean to have the number of edges be proportional to $n^{2m} = (n^m)^2$? It would mean that almost all vertices are adjacent. Well, if $n$ is small and $m$ is large, we expect that to happen: for two very long sequences from a very short alphabet, we expect at least one term to match.

On the other hand, if $n$ is large and $m$ is small, then we expect each vertex to have $m$ nearly-disjoint sets of neighbors: for each of the $m$ coordinates, it should have roughly $n^{m-1}$ neighbors that share that coordinate and do something else in the other $m-1$ coordinates. (There are some neighbors that share multiple coordinates, but this should be rare.) This leads to a degree of about $m n^{m-1}$, and about $\frac12 m n^{2m-1}$ total edges in the graph.